# htaccess: how to redirect one page to sub-page in same directory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have the following pages after enabling pretty urls in my CMS:

```
www.mydomain.com/cars/
www.mydomain.com/cars/carshome/
www.mydomain.com/cars/honda/
www.mydomain.com/cars/toyota/
...
```

I want all requests to `www.mydomain.com/cars/` to go to `www.mydomain.com/cars/carshome/`. Thus I've been trying to use in Apache .htaccess file (after pretty urls code executes):

```
Redirect 301 /cars https://www.mydomain.com/cars/carshome/
```

and the result is it goes in infinite loop:

(`https://www.mydomain.com/cars/carshome/carshome/carshome/...`).

How to resolve?

A second question would be, assuming the solution above needs to be changed here: how to redirect the other direction (from `www.mydomain.com/trucks/truckshome/` to `www.mydomain.com/trucks/`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Redirect` you can use `RedirectMatch` directive for its regex capability:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cars/?$ https://www.mydomain.com/cars/carshome/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cars/carshome/(.*)
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)$ /cars/carshome/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above will check to see if the url contains `cars/carshome/` and if it does, then nothing happens, but if it doesn't then it will redirect.

As for the second question, this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/trucks/truckshome/(.*)
RewriteRule ^trucks/truckshome/(.*)$ /trucks/$1 [R=301,L]
```